# Azure VM Extension List

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Looking to see if there's a easy way to retrieve all 'attached' extensions to a Virtual Machine whether it's Windows / Linux using PowerShell?

From my research, the 'Get-AzureRmVMExtension' extension requires that you provide a name parameter and doesn't allow the ability to list all associated.

Comment: Discovered that it's possible to retrieve all extensions using the 'Get-AzureRmVM' command and then selecting into the '.extensions' property.